# Angular 4: Returning promise from service goes into infinite loop

Tags: angular, promise, karma-jasmine, es6-promise

I am learning testing asynchronous code using Jasmine in Angular 4. So, I created a method in service

```
getResolvedData(): Promise<boolean> {
  return Promise.resolve(!!localStorage.getItem('token'));
}
```

And subscribing to this promise inside component's method

```
getAsyncData() {
  this.title = 'app';
  this.service.getResolvedData().then((data) => {
    return !data;
  });
}
```

Using this component's method `getAsyncData()` in the template as

```
<a>
    <span *ngIf="getAsyncData()">Async Data</span>
    <span *ngIf="!getAsyncData()">No Async Data</span>
</a>
```

But, the application does not load in browser on `ng serve --open`, due to an infinite loop which gets created once the HTML call the method inside the component.

How to resolve this?

Comment: Your getAsyncData() doesn't return anything. So it returns undefined, which is always falsy. So your code is equivalent to <a><span>No Async Data</span></a>

Comment: Moreover, your getAsyncData is invoked eveyrhime user interacts with the application (when detection change is invoked)

Answer (score 1):

I think that you probably wanted to do something like

```
 <span *ngIf="service.getResolvedData() | async">Async Data</span>
```

just remember that `service` must not be `private` to be used in component template

or

```
    asyncResult;
    ngOnInit() {
      this.title = 'app';
      this.service.getResolvedData().then((data) => {
        return asyncResult=!data;
      });
    }
```

and

```
<a>
    <span *ngIf="asyncResult">Async Data</span>
    <span *ngIf="!asyncResult">No Async Data</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all. What do you expect to get from it?

```
return !data;
```

Second you can simply use [async](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) pipe to resolve the Promise

Answer (score 0):

You can try to declare getSyncData() method inside ngOnInit().
Or you can call onClick function on button
E.g

```
export class DataComponent Implements OnInit{
ngOnInit(){
this.getSyncData()
}
}
```